# reorder performance with heap

Tags: c++, boost, heap-memory

I receive packet that i need to reorder according to a timestamp (64 bit).
I used boost::priority_queue. 
So each time i receive a packet i insert it in the queue 
Each 100 packet that i receive i pop timedout packet 
Usually size of heap is between 8000-15000 elements 
From google perf top it seems that the pop take much more cpu than the insert

```
 55.80%  [.] CrReorderMbuf::GetTimedOut(unsigned long, unsigned int&)
 14.59%  [.] CrReorderMbuf::Insert(rte_mbuf*, unsigned long&, unsigned int&)
```

1. Is there a better data structure or a heap not from boost
   I tried to use d_ary i didn't see change in performance
2. I didn't find from boost priority_queue/d_ary_heap a way to pop a bunch of elements.
   It could improve performance if i could iterate through the element by order and then remove them from heap, in one command.(i don't know what pop do perhaps it heapify on each pop)

This is the element i save in the heap:

```
struct SrMbufElement
{
    RU64 nTimeStamp;//timestamp of packet + timeout
    rte_mbuf * pMbuf;//pointer to mbuf
    RU32 nMbufIndex;
};
```

This is my GetTimeout function

```
rte_mbuf * CrReorderMbuf::GetTimedOut(RU64 pi_nCurrentTime,RU32 & po_nMbufIndex)
{
    if(!m_heapMBuff.empty()) 
    {
        const SrMbufElement &mbufElmnt = m_heapMBuff.top();
        if(mbufElmnt.nTimeStamp <= pi_nCurrentTime)
        {
            rte_mbuf *  pmBuf = mbufElmnt.pMbuf;
            po_nMbufIndex = mbufElmnt.nMbufIndex;
            m_heapMBuff.pop();
            return pmBuf;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but unless the packets you insert into the queue comes at a regular (or very short) interval, waiting for 100 packets before checking for timed out packets in the queue will be irregular, and maybe even quite a long time between checks. You should probably have some kind of timer to check when to handle timed out packets.